# VBA OptionButton True, False or Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have a couple of option buttons, OptionButton1 and OptionButton2:

[image]

These interact with a spreadsheet in the background, 'Sheet("AAP")', Column 19.

The Next and Previous buttons are set up to flick through the rows and display whatever is on the cells. This is done using a simple counter and a FOR Loop.

If value found (in col19) is "Yes", OptionButton1 will be activated.

If value found (in col19) is "No", OptionButton2 will be activated.

**CODE**

```
If .Cells(i, 19).Value = "Yes" 
  Me.OptionButton1 = True
ElseIf .Cells(i, 19).Value = "No" 
  Me.OptionButton2 = True
End If
```

This works fine.

**PROBLEM**

However, I am facing a problem when there is neither a "Yes" or a "No" in col19. For some reason, the loop will always define a boolean value for these option buttons when flicking through the rows.

I really want to leave both blank if the corresponding cell is blank.

```
        If .Cells(i, 19).Value = "Yes" Then
            Me.OptionButton1 = True
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 19).Value = "No" Then
            Me.OptionButton2 = True
        Else
            Me.OptionButton1 = ""
            Me.OptionButton2 = ""
        End If
```

But this does not work either.

Is there a clever work around to solve this issue?

I really appreciate this guys.

**POST-SCRIPT**

The idea is when the user notices that there is neither an accepted or a rejected request, then they will have to choose one. 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons will not work unless one of these is selected.

This is done using this code:

```
If Me.OptionButton1 = "" And Me.OptionButton2 = "" Then
   MsgBox ("You should either Accept or Reject a request.")
Exit Sub
End if
```

However, this does not work, because my previous loop does not leave the option buttons blanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you're setting strings (`""`) to variables which are Booleans (the `OptionButtons`).

Just do:

```
If .Cells(i, 19).Value = "Yes" Then
    Me.OptionButton1 = True
ElseIf .Cells(i, 19).Value = "No" Then
    Me.OptionButton2 = True
Else
    Me.OptionButton1 = False
    Me.OptionButton2 = False
End If
```

Comment: Obviously.. Silly me. Cheers mate.

Comment: @OdaySalim Np :) (Just bear in mind that I haven't used VBA in ages so I _might_ be wrong)

Comment: You are right. I just tested it and it worked. The whole thing works like magic now. Thanks man. 5 mins left until I mark as correct..